# Jackson Enum format for the one you don't own

Tags: java, jackson-databind

I am not able to find a way to serialize/deserialize an enum in my POJO. Most of the answers I found only deal with enum that you can change. I cannot change the enum.

Here is an example of my POJO.

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude.Include;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;

@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)
public class TitleRatingCheckItemResponse {
  private String titleId;

  @NotNull private Status status;

  @NoArgsConstructor
  @Data
  public static class Status {

    @NotNull
    private HttpStatus code;
  }
}
```

When I serialize the object to JSON, this is an example that I get

```
{
  "status": {
     "code": "OK"
  },
  "titleId": "titl_doc-1"
}
```

What I want to have is a JSON structure like the one below.

```
{
  "status": {
     "code": "200"
  },
  "titleId": "titl_doc-1"
}
```

To achieve the desired JSON output, I have to change `HttpStatus`. This is obvious not possible as I don't own the source code for `HttpStatus`. Is there any way I can do that?

Comment: Can you not have the `code` field as `Integer` instead of `HttpStatus`? Wherever you have a business logic with `HttpStatus`, you can use `HttpStatus valueOf(int statusCode)` to get `HttpStatus` object.

Comment: @MadhuBhat That wouldn't give the desired output either (`200` instead of `"200"`), while allowing to create invalid state.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov can even have it as a String field then right? In case there is not much of logic requiring `HttpStatus` object explicitly, you can have the field as any type. Of course, what I'm saying is quite obvious, but just wanted to see if we can get the job done without any custom deserializer.

Comment: @MadhuBhat Personally, I'd only consider this if the class is _only_ for conversion from/to JSON, no business logic involved. And even then probably not do it. Your mileage can vary, of course.

Comment: I meant just what you said, @AlexeyRomanov. Was just trying to understand more on the requirement here. Not denying your answer :)

Comment: @MadhuBhat I find that using `HttpStatus` allows me to enforce the value to come from the set of predefined values in `HttpStatus`. Having the field as either an `Integer` or `String` forces me to add validation to ensure that the value is valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create a class

   ```
   public class HttpStatusSerializer extends StdSerializer<HttpStatus> {
       public HttpStatusSerializer() {
           super(HttpStatus.class);
       }

       @Override
       public void serialize(HttpStatus value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider serializers) { 
           gen.writeString(String.valueOf(value.code())); // or whatever you want
       }
   }
   ```

   see [`StdSerializer` docs](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ser/std/StdSerializer.html). And another extending [`StdScalarDeserializer<HttpStatus>`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/deser/std/StdScalarDeserializer.html).
2. Register it in your `ObjectMapper`, wherever you create it:

   ```
   ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();    
   SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();
   module.addSerializer(HttpStatus.class, new HttpStatusSerializer());
   module.addDeserializer(HttpStatus.class, new HttpStatusDeserializer());
   mapper.registerModule(module);
   ```

   Or if you want to use the custom serializer just for this field and not for all `HttpStatus`es:

   ```
   @NotNull
   @JsonSerialize(using=HttpStatusSerializer.class)
   @JsonDeserialize(using=HttpStatusDeserializer.class)
   private HttpStatus code;
   ```

Comment: Wouldn't they need a deserialiser as well?

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov Thanks for the answer. I thought that there must be a way to do it without having to provide custom serializer and deserializer. At least it works with the solution you provided.

Comment: For a single field you can also just use a `Converter<HttpStatus, String>`, which would be simpler. I don't see a way to register it on an `ObjectMapper`. Some other JSON libary may be simpler for this use-case.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov Thanks for the suggestion.I didn't know that `Converter` exists.